# moving rectangles freezing to final state rather than performing each move

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to write a program that can show how sorting algorithms sort through a list. My algorithm works fine, and the program can visualise the starting state and the sorted state, but it doesn't seem to show each iteration, even though I am attempting to call the function within the sorting code.

Interestingly, without calling these functions, the program will instantly show the sorted list, but with them, it is very slow. This is actually good, because I want it to visualise the process which will take more time than it sorting in the fraction of a second that it normally would. However, in those few seconds that it takes to process, the bars do not move at all. It just freezes and then shows the sorted list instead of showing the bars moving (I don't want them to animate or anything, I just want to see the bars update at each step of the sort).

I have tried using `time.sleep()` to make the program wait for the new location before moving on, but this crashed the program. This is apparently because of the tkinter library.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import random

W = 1000
H = 800
buffer = 20
nums = []
numElements = 100
window = tk.Tk()
winSize = "{0}x{1}".format(str(W),str(H))
rectangles = []
w = tk.Canvas(window, width=W, height=H)

# Quick Sort algorithm to sort the list by count of word
def quickSort():
    list = nums
    def sorter(items, low, high):
        drawArr()
        if low < high:
            split = partition(items, low, high)
            sorter(items, low, split)
            sorter(items, split + 1, high)

    sorter(list, 0, len(list)-1)

    

# Partition method used for Quick Sort to get pivot point
def partition(list,start,end):
    low = start - 1
    high = end + 1

    pivot = list[(low + high) // 2]
    
    while True:
        low = low + 1
        while list[low] < pivot:
            low = low + 1

        high = high - 1
        while list[high] > pivot:
            high = high - 1

        if low >= high:
            return high

        list[low], list[high] = list[high], list[low]

        clearCanv()


def createArr():
    for x in range(numElements):
        nums.append(random.randrange(1, 100))
def clearCanv():
    for x in rectangles:
        w.delete(x)
    w.pack()
def drawArr():
    tempW = W - buffer
    posX = buffer
    for x in nums:
        try:
            rect = w.create_rectangle(posX, 500, posX+10, 50+nums[x]*2+250,fill='red')
            rectangles.append(rect)
            posX = posX + (W - buffer - buffer)/len(nums)
            w.pack()
        except:
            continue
        
createArr()
drawArr()

window.geometry(winSize)

greeting = tk.Label(text="Welcome to the Algorithmic Sorting Animator!")
greeting.pack(side = tk.TOP)


# Create a Button
btn = tk.Button(window, text = 'Quick Sort', command = quickSort)
btn.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to this question! you need to use the built in `update()` method whenever you want the window to update. In my case, thats `window.update()`, but for you, it could be `root.update()`